# Ubuntu One - Nautilus integration

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one, nautilus

I've uninstalled `Ubuntu One` from my system (Ubuntu 12.04) but I still get the `Ubuntu One` right click menu item (share, get link, etc) and the folders I used to sync still show `Ubuntu One`'s icons (synced, syncing, etc) These issues happening in `Nautilus`.

Is there any way to get rid of this integration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-client* python-ubuntuone-storage*
```

Also, delete all the related folders:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone ~/.cache/ubuntuone ~/.config/ubuntuone ~/Ubuntu\ One
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your answer. I'll try this method to see if this works.

Comment: Glad it worked! :)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and the case is opposite here. I never uninstalled Ubuntu One But the "Ubuntu one" option is not appearing on right click. any Idea @green7 ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not logged out and back in, the plug-in code is still loaded and running in Nautilus. Any application which uses plug-ins will have to be restarted after those plug-ins have been removed, before they will disappear from the interface. For Nautilus, the easiest way to do this is to simply log out, and then back in after a few seconds.

Comment: Nope, restarted the machine and the integration is still there.

Comment: Then you have not actually uninstalled Ubuntu One yet.

Comment: yes, I had uninstalled `Ubuntu One` at the time (I did it through the `Software Center`). Restarting the system did nothing. @green7's answer was what made the `Nautilus` integration go away.

Comment: You probably only removed the control panel, and not all of Ubuntu One, which is several applications and libraries that integrate with the system. Restarting the system didn't work, because you only removed one piece of the Ubuntu One suite; the control panel.

Comment: As I said, I removed the `Ubuntu One` entry in the `Software Center`, which should have been enough since it's what any regular user would do. It wasn't. To remove it completely I had to apply green7's answer which shouldn't have to be necessary. It should've gone away after uninstalling, it didn't. I shouldn't have had the need to use the terminal but I did.

Comment: And as I said, that isn't all of Ubuntu One. That is Software Center trying to be overly smart, and getting things wrong. Please file a bug report against Software Center explaining your expectations and what didn't happen.

Comment: It **should** be all of Ubuntu One because the Software Center is where regular users will go to get rid of stuff they don't want/like. I could file a bug against the SC for failing to uninstall, I could file a bug against Nautilus for maintaining integration with a half uninstalled software or I could file a bug against Ubuntu One for being overly invasive. Haven't decided yet, perhaps I'll do all three of them. Feel free to do the same.

Comment: I can tell you filing a bug against Nautilus or Ubuntu One in this respect will result in those bugs simply being marked invalid. There is nothing about Nautilus or Ubuntu One to blame here. Software Center is doing (showing) the wrong thing.